# Invoke-ASCmd to return error/warning in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, ssas

Running the PowerShell in my deployment pipeline:

```
Write-Host "Invoking deployment script... This may take several minutes."
Invoke-ASCmd -Server:$SsasServer -InputFile $path\$bim.xmla | Out-File $path\$bim.xml
Write-Host "Please check $path\$bim.xml as this is output of this deployment"
```

I want to take the output file of the Invoke-ASCmd: $bim.xml and determine if a warning exist or error exist. It would be ideal to return a warning messages to the console in my azure pipeline.

Example Warning message:

```
<return xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis"><root xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis:empty"><Exception xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis:exception" /><Messages xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis:exception"><Error ErrorCode="-1055784777" Description="The JSON DDL request failed with the following error: Failed to execute XMLA. Error returned: &#39;The column &#39;ProcessDateKey&#39; in table &#39;Financial Measures&#39; has invalid bindings specified.
&#39;.." Source="Microsoft SQL Server 2016 Analysis Services Managed Code Module" HelpFile="" /></Messages></root></return>
```

I am not sure if this is the correct way to handle this xml exactly. Here is my first draft:

```
[xml]$XmlDocument = Get-Content -Path $path\$bim.xml
if($XmlDocument.return.root.Messages.Error){
    foreach ($errorMessage in $XmlDocument.return.root.Messages.Error ){
        $message = $errorMessage.Description
        Write-Error $message
    }
    exit 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use if directly on the `Error` node, this could also be an `Error collection`. I recommend using a xPath query to find all the Error messages.

Also you can get directly the Xml output from Invoke-AsCmd into an xml variable:

```
[xml]$xmlResult = Invoke-ASCmd -Server:$SsasServer -InputFile $path\$bim.xmla
$errors = $xmlResult.return.root.Messages.SelectNodes("*[name() = 'Error']")
if($errors.Count -gt 0){
    foreach ($errorMessage in $errors){
        Write-Error $message.Description
    }
    exit 1
}
```